# What are correct values for aspect-ratio media query?

Tags: css, media-queries, aspect-ratio, node-sass

What are correct values for aspect-ratio media query?
Why the following media query is not working?
I want to separate cases with ratio>1 from ratio <1

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1399px) and (min-width: 1350px) and (min-aspect-ratio: 99/100) {
  div#aboutSLw {
    min-height: 1616.12131px !important;
    min-width: 0.45px !important; }
  div#aboutSLw div.topimage {
    min-height: 1616.12131px !important;
    min-width: 0.45px !important; }
  div.topimage img.vpimg {
    min-height: 1616.12131px !important;
    min-width: 0.45px !important; }
  div.topimage h2 {
    font-size: 1.85em !important; }
  div.topimage h2 span, div.topimage h2 span * {
    font-size: 1.45em !important; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main **[ratios](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ratio)** are:

- `4/3` - Traditional TV format in the 20th century.
- `16/9` - Modern "widescreen" TV format.
- `185/100` or `91/50` - The most common movie format since the 1960s.
- `239/100` - "Widescreen," anamorphic movie format.

However, keep in mind that **[aspect ratios](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/aspect-ratio)** are **[still spotty in Chrome](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/MediaQueries/20120229/reports/implement-report.html)**. For the time being, it's generally 'safer' to work with **[`resolution`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution)**, based on the dpi:

```
@media (resolution: 150dpi) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Alternatively there's the deprecated `min-device-pixel-ratio` (and optionally `orientation`). Annoyingly, there's no 'standard' on this, and you'll need to specify the vendor prefixes manually:

- **[`-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-moz-device-pixel-ratio)**
- **[`-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-moz-device-pixel-ratio)**
- `-o-min-device-pixel-ratio`

For example, to target the iPhone X you could use:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 
}
```

CSSTricks has a **[helpful cheatsheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)** showcasing the most common device queries in this regard.